# How to add lastmod to my application's sitemap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sitemap

I would like to add `lastmod` to my sitemap but I can't find a good example of how it should be formatted.

Here is what I'm current working with:

Controller:

```
class SitemapsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @events = Event.where(block_search_engines: false, status: 1)
  end
end
```

Show builder:

```
  xml.instruct!
  xml.urlset "xmlns" => "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" do

  @events.each do |event|
    xml.url do
      xml.loc present_url(event.slug)
      xml.priority 1.0
    end
  end
end
```

How would I implement it in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [sitemap.xml protocol specification](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html), the value should be formatted in the [W3C Datetime format](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime), which is basically ISO 8601.

> The date of last modification of the file. This date should be in W3C
>   Datetime format. This format allows you to omit the time portion, if
>   desired, and use YYYY-MM-DD.

The ruby Datetime contains [methods](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-iso8601) to get a ISO 8601 formatted output.

So you can do something like `xml.lastmod event.updated_at.xmlschema`.